# Context Menu item not showing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, registry

I am trying to place a new Menuitem in Explorer context menu and I cannot get it to work.

I am not getting any exceptions or error messages and I've set breakpoints and they're not being hit. And I've searched the registry and it's not there. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private const string MenuName = "Folder\\shell\\NewMenuOption";
    private const string Command = "Folder\\shell\\NewMenuOption\\command";

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var folder = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if(folder.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.ArchivePath = folder.SelectedPath;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                RegistryKey regmenu = null;
                RegistryKey regcmd = null;
                try
                {
                    regmenu = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(MenuName);
                    if (regmenu != null)
                        regmenu.SetValue("", "Archive");
                    regcmd = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(Command);
                    if (regcmd != null)
                        regcmd.SetValue("", Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Archiver.exe");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (regmenu != null)
                        regmenu.Close();
                    if (regcmd != null)
                        regcmd.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(MessageBox.Show("In order to use Archiver, you must first specify where your archive is. Do you want to continue?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Application.Restart();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Dispose(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run as admin? + where did you set your breakpoints?

Comment: @BramVanStrydonck, well, I wasn't sure where to set them since I thought the code was pretty OK, so I set them everywhere!

Comment: I'll try as admin. Argh. It's an Admin account - it shouldn't require me to run a damn app as admin!

Comment: So your code isn't even reaching the using statement?

Comment: @BramVanStrydonck I just ran the application as Administrator and it worked. I can't believe I forgot to run as admin. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Allright, can you mark my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your app as admin.
Making changes to the register may require admin rights.

Comment: may require may be requires.
As any action that changes something to the system must be run in full trust mode.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910(v=vs.110).aspx